# How to address CheckBoxField value in ASP.NET, c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check, whether a cell in a `<asp:CheckBoxField/>`, which was bounded to bool column in database, is or is not checked (i.e. True or False)?

For instance some function like

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[myCheckBoxFieldIndex].IsChecked()) {do my stuff}
    }
```

would do perfectly.

All I need is to access the value in the cell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First cast the control to a [`CheckBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var cell = e.Row.Cells[myCheckBoxFieldIndex];
var checkbox = cell.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Then use the `Checked` property

```
if (checkbox != null && checkbox.Checked) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

Comment: I do not see the `First()` function in `e.Row.Cells[myCheckBoxFieldIndex].Controls`.  Kinda confused here, do I need to be referencing something? Anyway I like your solution a lot, thx

Comment: `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` are extension methods in the Linq assembly but I forgot to mention you need to be using .net 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Needed to specify the `OfType<CheckBox>()` list to be able to choose `FirstOrDefault()`. Thanks, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`e.Row.Cells[myCheckBoxFieldIndex]` is type of DataGridViewCell.
You should cast this to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

```
var checkbox = e.Row.Cells[myCheckBoxFieldIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
if (checkbox != null && checkbox.Checked)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
       if ( ((CheckBox )e.Row .Cells [0].Controls [0]).Checked ==true )
         {
                      //do your stuff
          }
     }
 }
```